# What is the complement of a product of two sets?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I am given this information:

> Suppose $A=\{1,2,3\}$, $B=\{3,5\}$, $C=\{1,2,4,6,9\}$ and $U = \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,7,8,9\}$.
>   Enter "T" for each true, and "F" for each false statements.

There are problems like $|(A \times B)'| = 94$.

I *think* this is false, because:

$A \times B$ produces a set of tuples.

The absolute complement of a set $S$ is the set of all elements of $U$ that are not elements in the set $S$.

There are no tuples in $U$, so $A \times B$ has none of the elements of $U$, therefore, $(A \times B)'$ should produce the set $U$.

If this thinking is true, then $|(A \times B)'| = 10$

Have I missed something/is my thinking correct?

Comment: I could imagine that the universal set for the product is intended to be $U\times U$ which is of size $100$, putting $|(A\times B)'|=100-6=94$.  Under some interpretations, the complement of a set $A$ is the set $A^c$ such that $A\cup A^c = U$.  Since $A\times B$ contains things not in $U$ in the first place, this second definition doesn't make sense to talk about since there is no set such that unioned with $A\times B$ will produce $U$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion your reasoning is almost correct as it is never stated the universal set for ordered pairs is $U \times U$.

$A \times B \not \subset U$ so $(A \times B)'$ is a meaningless statement and the question makes no sense.

In my opinion.

However it is obviously the intended case that the universal set for ordered pairs is intended $U \times U$.

$|U \times U| = 10*10 = 10$

$|A \times B| = 2*3 = 6$ so $|(A \times B)'|=94$.

=====

I say "Phooey on everything".

Comment: Oh, so the answer.... I'm pretty sure the answer is intended to by T.  .... unless it isn't... yeah, you should probably talk to the person writing the problems.  It's not clear.